# Is it ok to say that the software version is "frozen"? Why?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality, technology

I often hear phrases like code freeze, version freeze but I have never heard of *frozen* being used in this context.

Comment: Sure.  If you're in code freeze then the code base is frozen.

Comment: Are you asking if it is acceptable to **either** say that code can freeze or be frozen or asking if the specific word _frozen_  is as appropriate as _freeze_, depending on context?

Comment: Also note that there should always be an explanation for why software is frozen. For example, one good reason to freeze a version is if it is implemented or being implemented.

Comment: This clarifies hang, freeze and crash, and I didn't want to just post the entire page:https://www.cyberlink.com/support/faq-content.do?id=14592 Grammatically, a program freezes. The program would be frozen. A frozen program.

Comment: @Lambie That is a different meaning of "freeze". Application freeze = unresponsive, version freeze = not being updated at present.

Comment: There is a parallel in the language used to discuss pensions. If one leaves a pension scheme (possibly by changing a job) before reaching pension age the pension is said to be _frozen_ in value. This is, of course, completely different from the software context but is linguistically similar to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

In modern software Version is often associated with Snapshot, Tag or Release. Version cannot be modified, you'll often find MD5 checksum for version releases. Phrase "version freeze" does not make much sense to me, but probably is used to describe pre-release feature freeze.

If you are working with "code branches" then you could say "code in this branch is frozen".

So as long as you apply "frozen" to the correct noun - specification, code, feature - it should be ok.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze_(software_engineering).